# mixture of inner and outer joins in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Having trouble with how to construct my sql for this scenario.
I have 3 tables:

**Person table:**

```
ID

--

A
```

**FACT_1 table:**

```
Person_ID DAY metric

--------------------

A         1   x

A         2   y
```

**FACT_2 table:**

```
Person_ID DAY metric

--------------------

A         3   a

A         2   b
```

I would like the result to be:

```
Person_ID DAY metric1 metric2

-----------------------------

A         1   x       [null]

A         2   y       b

A         3   [null]  a
```

So it's like an outer join on the person Id and the Day to each fact table individually.. but i need to tie the two metrics together when the person and day are the same.
The fact tables can be quite large, so need to keep that in mind.

sorry about the formatting.. not familiar with it

Comment: "The fact tables can be quite large, so need to keep that in mind." MySQL can handle millions off records just fine when indexed correctly so i dont see anny problems here.

Comment: yeah, just something to keep in mind if there are multiple ways to achieve the result... not my main priority right now - firstly just need to get the right results

Comment: the expected results looks like you want to combination  with JOIN(s) with a "pivot" or "records to columns" conversion. If you search stackoverflow with "MySQL pivot" and "MySQL records to columns" you should find answers on stackoverflow how to do this.. So basically this question is a duplicate of existing questions

Comment: not sure i follow.. i don't *think i'm doing any pivoting.. its just joining the tables together, rows are still rows..but using a weird mix of outer vs inner that i can't figure out

Comment: What's actually the difference between the fact_1 and fact_2 tables? They appear to have the same columns. If two tables have the same columns, it's usually a sign that they should in fact be one single table, possibly with an extra column which is used to distinguish the records from each other (e.g. a Fact_ID or something, in this case) based on whatever it was which caused them to be written to a different table in the old design.

Comment: i have simplified the model considerably.   They are very different metric tables. They just have the person and the day columns in common

Comment: "not sure i follow.. i don't *think i'm doing any pivoting.. its just joining the tables together, rows are still rows..but using a weird mix of outer vs inner that i can't figure out –" Can you provide a better example on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com? I believe there are atleast three different methods 1) pivot method, 2) multiple LEFT JOINs and  3) co-related subqueries ordered by best to worst to get the results you need.

Comment: Don't have two fact tables. There appears to be no justification for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're grabbing other data from the Person table, you don't need it for this query. You could join it to the UNION, though, if need be.

```
SELECT
   u.Person_ID
  ,u.DAY
  ,MAX(u.metric1) AS metric1
  ,MAX(u.metric2) AS metric2
FROM 
(
  SELECT
     f1.Person_ID
    ,f1.DAY
    ,f1.metric AS metric1
    ,NULL AS metric2
  FROM 
    Fact_1 AS f1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
     f2.Person_ID
    ,f2.DAY
    ,NULL AS metric1
    ,f2.metric AS metric2
  FROM 
    Fact_2 AS f2
) AS u
GROUP BY
   u.Person_ID
  ,u.DAY

Results:
+-----------+-----+---------+---------+
| Person_ID | DAY | metric1 | metric2 |
+-----------+-----+---------+---------+
| A         |   1 | x       | NULL    |
| A         |   2 | y       | b       |
| A         |   3 | NULL    | a       |
+-----------+-----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: thanks.. this works, and brings up the point that the group by is needed, and i can perform what i need there (ie. a SUM instead of a max, etc).

Answer (score 1):

[**Live demo here**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/npEVjyPzUEExW7MkK7JxyE/0)

You could achieve your result by doing a `FULL JOIN` on fact tables which MySQL does not support but it can be emulated using two queries with `LEFT JOIN` and then combined with `UNION`. In both queries we check if a person exists in `person` table in `WHERE` clause (twice just to limit amount of rows being processed as soon as possible):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(f.p1, f.p2) as person_id,
  COALESCE(f.d1, f.d2) as day,
  m1 as metric1,
  m2 as metric2
FROM (
SELECT f1.person_id as p1,f1.day as d1,f1.metric as m1,f2.person_id as p2,f2.day as d2,f2.metric as m2 
FROM fact_1 f1
LEFT JOIN fact_2 f2 ON f1.person_id = f2.person_id and f1.day = f2.day
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM person p WHERE p.id = f1.person_id)
UNION
SELECT f1.person_id as p1,f1.day as d1,f1.metric as m1,f2.person_id as p2,f2.day as d2,f2.metric as m2 
FROM fact_2 f2
LEFT JOIN fact_1 f1 ON f1.person_id = f2.person_id and f1.day = f2.day
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM person p WHERE p.id = f2.person_id)
) f
ORDER BY person_id, day
```

This gives result:

```
person_id     day   metric1    metric2
---------------------------------------
A              1       x        null
A              2       y         b
A              3      null       a
```

If you are certain that `person_id` is correct in fact tables (you have enforced it in foreign key constraints or checking it somehow differently) you could skip the `WHERE EXISTS` check to improve performance.

Consider creating index on `fact_1(person_id, day)` and `fact_2(person_id, day)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a recordset of unique days:

```
 select DAY from FACT_1 
 union select DAY from FACT_2
```

You could also get days as a sequence of numbers (even using a recursive CTE if you're using the latest version of MySQL):

```
select * from (
    select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    -- ...
) Days
```

You could `CROSS JOIN` this to the `Person` table, then left join each of the `FACT` tables to get what you want:

```
select
    Person.`ID`
    ,Days.Day
    ,FACT_1.metric metric1
    ,FACT_2.metric metric2
from Person
    cross join 
    (    select DAY from FACT_1 
         union select DAY from FACT_2
    ) DAYS 
    left join FACT_1 on
        FACT_1.Person_ID = Person.`ID`
        and FACT_1.Day = Days.Day
    left join FACT_2 on
        FACT_2.Person_ID = Person.`ID`
        and FACT_2.Day = Days.Day
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd9a37/14/0).

Comment: thanks.. this looks like it works, but performs a Cartesian product basically, if both facts have multiple entries for a person/day. I didn't realise that was possible in the solution, but since it is, it's not quite what i need. I would rather be given the choice on what to do, which the group by option does. I suppose i could just wrap your up with a group by and do so.

Comment: Again, if you don't want to go the route of the cartesian product, you could hard-code your days (I'm not sure how high your `Day` values go up to, so it might get tedious). You could also encapsulate the days in a separate view.